# java; TextField wont go Under the JLabel

Tags: java, textfield

NOTE: My English isn't the best so Please Don't mind too much Grammar Mistakes.

Hey there, Java Starter here, Anyways i was Testing a mini "beta" version of the Program i'm planning to code, So i made a TextField And it wont go Under my JLabel i made, i tried to use BorderLayout.PAGE_END to get it under / at the bottom but it won't get it. Here's the Code:

```
package test;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class TextTest {
    private static TextField field;
    private static void createGUI() {
        Font a = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 0);
        Font size = a.deriveFont(20f);
        JLabel test = new JLabel("");
        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        test.setText("<html> Welcome to the EMOJI Translator! Type the <br> Emoji in the Text Area And hit Enter! and it will say What the emoji means! <html>");
        test.setFont(size);
        field = new TextField(2);
        field.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String test = field.getText();
                String search1 = ":D";
                if(test.equals(search1)) {
                    System.out.println("This is an Happy Smiley.");
                }

            }});
        JFrame b = new JFrame("TEST");
        b.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,350));
        b.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.getContentPane().add(field, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        b.getContentPane().add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        b.pack();
        b.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createGUI();


    }




}
```

Here's a Link to the screenshot of how it ended looking in my Computer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRp8D.jpg

If you know Whats wrong please respond to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use properties of `BorderLayout` for a gui make with `FlowLayout`. In Java, you cannot mix different layout managers, by doing this the layout properties will be ignored.

You should set you layout manager to `BorderLayout`, so it accepts your properties:

```
b.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed my problem, didn't noticed that.

Comment: Hi @JavaStarter if resolved then please accept the solution provided by Ferrybig.